# Consulta SQL me da resultado en blanco

Tags: sql

Hola tengo una consulta urgente.
Tengo 3 tablas, Equipos, Ligas y Fixture
La idea es que con sus respectivas claves foraneas en la tabla Fixture se "unan" los datos de Equipos y Ligas.

La consulta la estoy formulando asi:

```
SELECT fixture.idFixture, fixture.idLocal, equipos.Nombre , fixture.idVisitante , equipos.Nombre , ligas.Ligas 
from pronos.equipos, pronos.ligas, pronos.fixture
**where fixture.idLocal = equipos.idEquipos
AND fixture.idVisitante = equipos.idEquipos**
and ligas.idLigas = fixture.idLiga;
```

me da un resultado en blanco.

Comment: Pon en las etiquetas qué base de datos utilizas, además de adjuntar un [repro]: es necesario que des datos de ejemplo.

Comment: cómo puede ser el mismo `idEquipo` igual tanto al `idLocal` y `idVisitante`?. Te falta un join con la misma tabla `equipos` de nuevo

Comment: Estás intentando hacer una consulta con múltiples tablas pero no tienes un JOIN por ningún lado

Comment: @ndrs si bien esta forma de hacer joins está deprecada y es obsoleta, siguen siendo joins

Comment: Urgente? Lo dudamos mucho, [pero aquí se atienden consultas urgentes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%c3%a9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo/4152#4152). Necesitaremos los datos de entrada y la salida esperada. Por legibilidad, y para quienes van a mantener tu código en el futuro, usa `JOINS` en lugar de comas... ugh!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El problema es que estás usando solo una vez la tabla `Equipos`, lo que obviamente no puede cumplir las condiciones de ser igual al equipo local Y al equipo visitante.

Y algo extra a corregir es que uses `JOIN`s explícitos en vez de estos `JOIN`s implícitos que están deprecados hace más de 20 años.

```
SELECT 
    f.idFixture, 
    f.idLocal, 
    loc.Nombre NombreLocal, 
    f.idVisitante, 
    vis.Nombre NombreVisita, 
    l.Ligas 
FROM pronos.equipos loc
JOIN pronos.fixture f
    ON f.idLocal = loc.idEquipos
JOIN pronos.equipos vis
    ON f.idLocal = vis.idEquipos
JOIN pronos.ligas l
    ON l.idLigas = f.idLiga
;
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta. Entiendo, como desarrollador, que la palabra *deprecated* aparece en muchos lugares, y la utilizamos como un préstamo lingüístico, sin embargo, su traducción literal es "obsoleto/a" y su definición corresponde exactamente al espíritu de la palabra en inglés. Además, suena raro en español, no crees?

Answer (score 2):

Lo que pasa es que estás tratando de unir las tablas fixture y equipos usando dos columnas de la primera y una columna de la segunda. Al momento de las consultas, tienes que pensar en que cada tabla representa una entidad y puede tener varias instancias según lo que represente en cada llamada. En este caso, necesitas dos instancias de la tabla equipos: una para representar al equipo local y otra para representar al equipo visitante.

Cambié un poco la estructura de tu consulta para mostrar mejores prácticas al momento de escribir código SQL

```
SELECT f.idFixture, 
    f.idLocal, 
    el.Nombre , 
    f.idVisitante , 
    ev.Nombre , 
    l.Ligas 
FROM pronos.fixture AS f
JOIN pronos.ligas   AS l  ON f.idLiga      = l.idLigas
JOIN pronos.equipos AS el ON f.idLocal     = el.idEquipos
JOIN pronos.equipos AS ev ON f.idVisitante = ev.idEquipos;
```